Assistance Needed with Hosting PHP Application on Ubuntu 20.04LTS with Apache2
Hello Ubuntu Community,
I am encountering an issue while hosting a PHP application on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using Apache2. Below are the specific requirements for my setup:
System Setup:

The Ubuntu system has two local users (user1 and user2).
Both users have their home directories under /var/www/html/ (i.e., /var/www/html/user1 and
/var/www/html/user2).
Neither user is part of the www-data group.
The permissions for the webroot directories should be set to 701 recursively.

Objective: The primary reason for setting the group permission to 0 is to prevent each local user from reading or writing to each other's files or folders. Additionally, this setup is intended to allow future group policies to be implemented without affecting this specific requirement (i.e., preventing read/write access between users).
Could you please advise on how to achieve this configuration effectively?
Thank you for your assistance.
